# How to determine the language currently in use for browser in classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

Is there ASP code which can retrieve the users current language?  In javascript I know this works...

```
if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape')
  var language = navigator.language;
else
  var language = navigator.userLanguage;
```

But is there an equivalent for ASP/VBScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you need this:
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE")

Comment: Yep. This may consist of multiple values, eg "da-DK,en-UK", so be careful to parse it accordingly.

Comment: Yeh there are multiple values for how I'm working with things but this will do it.  Thanks all.